# Not able to run blob trigger when published on azure functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have created a simple blob trigger in visual studio for which **init**.py is as below

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
   logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
             f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
             f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

and function.json is as below

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
     {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "mycontainer/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
     }
    ]
}
```

local.settings.json looks as below

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;  AccountName=****;AccountKey=*****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
   }
}
```

This code works fine with visual studio on local machine. But when published on azure portal it can not read blob path from function.json and gives error as

```
Invalid blob path specified : ''. Blob identifiers must be in the format 'container/blob'.
```

I have published function using command to push contains of local.settings.json.

```
func azure functionapp publish FUNCTIONNAME --build-native-deps --publish-local-settings -i
```

.
Can anyone please guid me what I am missing after publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the run button in the Azure portal to test your function? The way this works for blob triggers is that in the 'Test' tab on the right hand side, you can specify the name of the blob you want to manually send a trigger event for, forcing your function to run:﻿

[image]

The idea is that you should edit the contents of the request body box and put in the path to a valid blob in your account. That way the trigger runs and finds the blob and retrieves it. So if you don't modify the request body box, then it will look for a blob and fail to find it and throw the 404 error.

Also please take a look at below document for configuring container name

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#storage-blob-trigger

Also please verify if you setting has been published in the portal or not.

```
func azure functionapp publish "functionname" --publish-local-settings
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohit for quick response. I have already tested using 'Test' window and it is working fine. As C#  version of azure function is editable, this test string persist(after saving) and blobtrigger works fine. But for python it is preview version and  does not persists the contains of test window. I need the solution for this.

Comment: Will check and get back. As it is in a preview , then we need to look for workaround then.

Comment: @ Mohit Verma - MSFT It will be a great help if you can check how to persist the string of test window for python version

Comment: Can you please download the template from here ans try to deploy it https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates. Sample.dat file ensures the default value in the test lab tab. Please ensure it persist in the portal after deployment.

Comment: Sample.dat contains sample input data for each template. The Run text box in the portal will be populated by the contents of the sample.dat file. If it still doesn't work , meanwhile will check at my end and update